# How to set readonly all input beside input that user try to fill data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How to set `readonly` all input except input that user try to fill data ?

---

When user loads page `index.php` and tries to fill data into EG: `<input id="edValue2" ...>`, I want to set readonly all input except `<input id="edValue2" ...>`

But my code not work, how can i do ?

**index.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form-id" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<?PHP
    for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
        {
?>
            <input id="edValue<?PHP echo $i; ?>" type="text" onKeyUp="send_it_register_to_hidden_input<?PHP echo $i; ?>()" onKeyPress="send_it_register_to_hidden_input<?PHP echo $i; ?>()"><br>
<?PHP
        }
?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="lblValue" value="">
    <input type="text" id="lblValue_number" value="">
</form>
</body>



<?PHP
    for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
        {
?>
            <script>
            function send_it_register_to_hidden_input<?PHP echo $i; ?>()
                {
                    lblValue.value = $("#edValue<?PHP echo $i; ?>").val();                    
                    lblValue_number.value = <?PHP echo $i; ?>; 

                    Check_register_it();
                }
            </script> 
<?PHP
        }
?>   





<script>
function Check_register_it()
   {
       $('#form-id input').attr('disabled','disabled'); //disable all
       $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); //enable the one that triggers the event
   }
</script> 




</html>
```

Comment: Try my answer . It will definetly work for you . It's a general solution .No matter what `input` fields have their `ids` .

Comment: even if you use `TAB` then also it will work .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest don't create functions like that. It just makes your codes complicated. Use `classes` in this case so that you don't need to setup functions for each id that you want to manipulate:

```
<body>
<form id="form-id" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<?PHP for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) { ?>
    <input class="input_boxes" type="text" data-i="<?php echo $i; ?>"><br/>
<?PHP } ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="lblValue" value="">
    <input type="text" id="lblValue_number" value="">
</form>
</body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.input_boxes').on('keyup', function(e){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var i_val = $(this).attr('data-i');
    $('#lblValue').val(i_val);
    $('#lblValue_number').val(value);
    $('input').prop('readonly', true);
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: on your code , i not get `$i` value in input `name="lblValue_number"`

How can i do ?

Comment: @srimonretswe yeah i omitted that one, i revised my answer, kindly check it again

Comment: How to use `keyup` and `keypress` together on your code .

Comment: @srimonretswe you could bind events inside on `$('.input_boxes').on('keyup keypress')`

Comment: I have some question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193394/how-to-show-result-data-in-id-follow-value-in-input-type-text  But i not have best answer. Colud you please give me some advice. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all inputs are children of the same element (i.e. siblings), you can use jQuery to do this easily:

```
$('input').on('focus', function(){
    $('input').removeAttr('readonly');
    $(this).siblings().attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/qukohosafuje/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
  $("input").on('keyup', function () {
        $('input').not(this).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
  });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xes853eL/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all JQuery statement within:

```
$(function(){
     //put your JQuery code here
});
```

Try and let me know if now works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the html attribute of readonly for the inputs you don't want users to fill.
e.g

```
<input type="text" id="lblValue" value="" readonly>
```

if you would required the readonly inputs to be accessible after the necessary input has been filled, you can use jquery to trigger the event.

e.g

```
$('input').keyUp(function(){
    if($('#edValue2').val()!=""){
        $('input:not("#edValue2")').removeAttr('readonly');
```

})