# How to show result data in id follow value in input type text?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to show result data in id `myplace` follow value in `id="number"`

if

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="5">
```

i want to show result in `id="myplace5"`

if

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="7">
```

i want to show result in `id="myplace7"`

How can i do that ?

```
<script>
function Check_register()
   {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form_setup').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('input').prop('readonly', false); // this line will enable all input after success //
                    $('#myplace').show();
                    $('#myplace').html(data);
                }
            }
        )
    }, 2000);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: make **JSfiddle** for more understanding. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `data` is html containing `<input id="number" />`. If so, you can do:

```
$('#myplace'+ $(data).find("#number").val()).html(data);
```

Comment: i replace `$('#myplace').show();
          $('#myplace').html(data);`
with

`$('#myplace'+ $(data).find("#number").val()).show();
$('#myplace'+ $(data).find("#number").val()).html(data);`


But not work, how can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Since '*Myplace*' is an input element, you can't use 'text' or 'html' as you would normally.

Instead what you need to do is use jQuerys 'val' function, as follows:

```
$("#myplace").val(html.data);
```

'html.data' will contain the data that you obtained from your web service, and the call to vall will make sure that it's added to the elements value property.